# Selenium webdriver Thread sleep not working as expected

Tags: java, mysql, image, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to retrieve an image from my mySql database and upload it on my webpage, in a field which is meant to upload image files from hard disk.

I am using java, eclipse and selenium webdriver.

My question is, is it possible ? If yes, how ?

Comment: sorry for the title....was for another issue....fixed it but didn't close the stackoverflow window and later typed the new problem into it by mistake

Comment: Selenium doesn't connect to a database, Java, or a third party Java library, has an API to allow you to connect to a database, Selenium doesn't even come into it.

Comment: Thats right. I mentioned Selenium because I was hoping it'd have a way to upload an image blob where an image is needed. Now I think its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is:)Pull it from the DB, save it to some location on your drive (this can be done for instance in `@Before` with JUnit framework) and then use `driver.sendKeys(pathToImageOnDrive)`.

Comment: Yes that is a way but what i am looking for i is without saving the images into new files, like we retrieve texts, store in variables and use them in our programs.

Comment: I think there is no other way because you can only upload file with Selenium by passing path to that file to the input box which does the file upload.